# How change the GroupStyle color?

Tags: wpf

I've different `GroupStyle` that have this structure:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                                    <Expander.Header>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                            <TextBlock Text=" Campionati" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Expander.Header>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                </Expander>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
```

now I want understand how can change the background color of the `GroupStyle`, in particular, now this have the default color of mahapp framework:

[image]

also is possible set the height dimension? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Background of the Expander:

`<Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="Red">`
Or if you want to keep the Themes of Mahapps you should use one of the predefined Brushes in Mahapps, and change the Expander Style, because the Expander related with the active Accent.

**EDIT**

Add this style to The Resource:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomExpanderHeaderStyle"  BasedOn="{DynamicResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Circle"
                                 Width="19"
                                 Height="19"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                <Path x:Name="Arrow"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              StrokeThickness="2"
                              Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="false" />
                                <controls:ContentControlEx Grid.Column="1"
                                                   Margin="4 0 0 0"
                                                   Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                   HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                   VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                   Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                   ContentCharacterCasing="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing)}"
                                                   ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                                   ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                   ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
                                                   RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush2}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush2}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource BlackColorBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource BlackColorBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

In the GroupStyle:

```
    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Expander controls:ExpanderHelper.HeaderDownStyle="{StaticResource CustomExpanderHeaderStyle}" IsExpanded="True">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text=" Campionati" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
```

Do not forgot to add Xmlns:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

Comment: and fot the height?

Comment: Set the Height and the Background in the ExpanderHeaderStyle.